# Unable to re-encode base64 decoded png image file data

Tags: python, png

I have a problem reading `png` files with python, I have a web server to save data and read data, but my side of save data receive image in base64 to convert this to png file, with this.

I create path to image, that result like `images/2017-07-23-18-46-30st1folio1.png` for example.

`imgBase64` contains a image send from my app (other theme).
`path="images/"+str(date_time_path)+str(data['ST_string'])+str(data['Folio_string'])+".png`"

Then I save my data with this

```
with open(path, "wb") as fh:
    fh.write(imgBase64.decode('base64'))
```

In this moment I can see my photos without problems.

But my problem is when I try read this data with this

```
for ix in photos:
     print "Access to path, "+ "./"+str(ix.idSTFolio.path_img)
     encoded_string = None
     with open("./"+str(ix.idSTFolio.path_img), "rb") as image_file:
           encoded_string = b64encode(image_file.read())
     print "encoded -> ", encoded_string
```

In each iteration I can see this route, when I print first line I see this:

```
./images/2017-07-23-18-46-30st1folio1.png
```

but the last line only ever **prints the empty string**, I don't know why. If my file exists, and I try writing `foo.zip` (which doesn't exist) the return error is that it doesn't exist, but when I try printing `image_file`, I get this instead:

```
<open file u'./images/2017-07-23-18-46-30st1folio1.png', mode 'rb' at 0x108123db0>
```

When I run my web server my path is `/Users/MyComputer/Documents/Codes/trackerServer` and I have folder `/images` in this route with my images sent previously. Any ideas?

**Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot from Atom editor with my images]

Comment: what are imgBase64.decode and b64encode? My guess is that one, or both,  don't work correctly or are not compatible somehow

Comment: imgBase64 is a variable to received from my app a image in base64, like this   `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE....9CQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==`  with this type `<type 'unicode'>` and b64encode is a definition from `from base64 import b64encode, b64decode`

Comment: you can view the images correctly in the output directory? Is x.idSTFolio.path_img pointing to the same path? Otherwise find out what the result/length of image_file.read() is before running it through b64encode. I suspect you're reading empty files somehow.  Are you perhaps reading and writing the directory at the same time?

Comment: See if the data from `imgBase64.decode('base64')` is the same as what ends up in `encoded_string` when it's read back. If it's not, that's the source of the problem. In other words, start verifying your assumptions when debugging something you _think_ ought work, but doesn't...

Comment: Yes, I update my question, I realice this test and return `True`, `print "path -> ", os.path.isfile("./"+str(ix.idSTFolio.path_img))`, insert_data and get_data are different routes from my web server.

Comment: @martineau I don't understand your idea, please explain me

Comment: @martineau I print imgBase64 and imgBase64.decode('base64') and the first is the same result ever and imgBase64.decode('base64') print thing like this `?PNG IHDRB?qy?  iCCPICC ProfileH??WT?????Z RB?H?.?K?6B ? `

Comment: My idea was simply that the data `imgBase64.decode('base64')` returned, which was written to the file, should be exactly what you get after it's re-encoded using the `b64encode(image_file.read())` call. This is something you can have the _script_ check to make sure whether it's exactly the same or not. If it's not, that's the problem. Trying to do it visually may be too difficult since it's mostly all binary data.

Comment: P.S. You're getting the `<open file u'./images/2017-07-23-18-46-30st1folio1.png', mode 'rb' at 0x108123db0>` printed because that's the Python **file object**. The data actually contained **in the file** is whatever `image_file.read()` returns the first time it's called (you can't do it more than once without rewinding the file in-between).